# Ignore a substring in RegEx pattern

Tags: regex

I want to ignore the certain substring in the result match, not exclude if the substring exists.

*For example*

I have the text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eliti qwer-
ty egeet qwewerty lectus. Proinera risus massa, placerat in q-
werty sed, tincidunt in nunci auspendisse vel dolor qwerty qw-
erty, molestie nisl sit amet, qwerty ligula curabitur ipsum,
euismod at augue at, dapibus feugiat qweerty
```

I need to find all `qwerty`, even if it contains `-\n`.

My decision is adding `(?:-\n)?` after every char:

`/q(?:-\n)?w(?:-\n)?e(?:-\n)?r(?:-\n)?t(?:-\n)?y/gm`

But it looks bulky *(even for the example that contains only 6 chars)* and it is too hard to modify the regex later, **is there a magic to make the regex shorter?**

Comment: I think you are using Javascript, but in some flavours you could use a capturing group and a  [subroutine](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines) `q((?:-\n)?)w(?1)e(?1)r(?1)t(?1)y` https://regex101.com/r/7jUjRy/1/

Answer (score 0):

No, regex is not good at this kind of match. The easiest way would be to remove `-` and `\n` first.